# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli'

Tags: php, raspberry-pi

I've been trying to load `"localhost/phpmyadmin"` and the error I receive is:

> The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.
>   See our documentation for more information.

For resolving that I tried many solutions given on similar issue but couldn't resolve mine.

I tried doing everything from these questions, but nothing helped:

[The mysqli|mysql extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration](https://askubuntu.com/questions/891490/the-mysqlimysql-extension-is-missing-please-check-your-php-configuration)

[Sqli extension missing after phpmyadmin installation, setting up LAMP](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/sqli-extension-missing-after-phpmyadmin-installation-setting-up-lamp/38310)

[How to solve 'The mysqli extension is missing' for PHPmyadmin under NGINX?](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2160103)

[phpMyAdmin MySQLi extension error](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/24911/phpmyadmin-mysqli-extension-error)

Comment: can you add infos about your host , php version, how you installed php?

Comment: did you restart php after applying solutions?

Comment: My host, localhost,

Comment: My host, localhost, php version 7.2.19 , 
I installed php by this method, 
sudo apt install php7.1 libapache2-mod-php7.1 php7.1-common php7.1-gmp php7.1-curl php7.1-soap php7.1-bcmath php7.1-intl php7.1-mbstring php7.1-xmlrpc php7.1-mcrypt php7.1-mysql php7.1-gd php7.1-xml php7.1-cli php7.1-zip
 
And then ,

sudo nano /etc/php/7.1/apache2/php.ini